# docusign api: adding agent recipient

Tags: docusignapi

Can you please help me with my below query?
I am currently using demologin to connect to docusign and sending an envelope with 3 recipients - agent, signer , signer. My agent should be able to review and change the email address and name of the first signer. I have set below tags true for agent.

```
<canEditRecipientEmails>true</canEditRecipientEmails> 
<canEditRecipientNames>true</canEditRecipientNames>
```

I have also added below tags to my first signer though they have made no effect:

```
<agentCanEditEmail>true</agentCanEditEmail>
<agentCanEditName>true</agentCanEditName>
```

When agent receives an email and opens it, it says:  "There are no recipients to address.
Click 'Complete and Send' to complete your portion of this envelope."
I am expecting below message 
"You have been asked to review and add recipient information.
Please enter the email address and name for the associated role and click 'Complete and Send'."
In my xml if I leave signer1 email address and name then it is working fine, agent can enter the email address and name.
Can you please let me know if anything wrong with my xml:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
    <emailSubject>Total Gas  Power Contract for Signature</emailSubject>
    <status>sent</status>
    <documents>  <document>  <name>  documentName 
    </name>  <documentId>1</documentId>  <order>1</order> 
    </document>  </documents>                
    <recipients> 
    <agents>  <agent>  <email>  custEmail  </email> 
    <name>  recipientNameCust  </name> 
     <RoleName>Broker</RoleName>
    <recipientId>1</recipientId> 
    <routingOrder>1</routingOrder> 
    <canEditRecipientEmails>true</canEditRecipientEmails> 
    <canEditRecipientNames>true</canEditRecipientNames> 
    </agent>  </agents> 
    <signers>  <signer> 
    <email>  custEmail  </email>  <name>  recipientNameCust  </name> 
     <RoleName>Customer</RoleName>
    <recipientId>2</recipientId> 
    <routingOrder>2</routingOrder> 
    <agentCanEditEmail>true</agentCanEditEmail> 
    <agentCanEditName>true</agentCanEditName> 
     <tabs> 
    <signHereTabs> 
    <signHere> 
    <anchorString>SIGNED on behalf of the Customer</anchorString> 
    <anchorXOffset>10</anchorXOffset> 
    <anchorYOffset>50</anchorYOffset> 
    <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent> 
    <anchorUnits>Pixels</anchorUnits> 
    <documentId>1</documentId>  <recipientId>2</recipientId> 
    <tabLabel>Sign Here1</tabLabel>  <name>SignHere1</name> 
    </signHere>  </signHereTabs> 
    </tabs>         
    </signer> 
    <signer>  <email>  receipientEmail  </email> 
    <name>  recipientNameTotal  </name> 
    <RoleName>Counter Signee</RoleName>
    <recipientId>3</recipientId> 
    <routingOrder>3</routingOrder>  <tabs> 
    <signHereTabs> 
    <signHere> 
    <anchorString>SIGNED on behalf of Total Gas</anchorString> 
    <anchorXOffset>10</anchorXOffset> 
    <anchorYOffset>50</anchorYOffset> 
    <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent> 
    <anchorUnits>Pixels</anchorUnits> 
    <documentId>1</documentId>  <recipientId>3</recipientId> 
    <tabLabel>Sign Here2</tabLabel>  <name>SignHere2</name> 
    </signHere>  </signHereTabs>  </tabs> 
    </signer>  </signers> 
    </recipients> 
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: Are you using a template in this request or are you sending from a local document?  I see that you are adding a document near the top of the xml, which makes me think local document.  However I also see that you are assigning template recipient roles to your recipients by setting the `<roleName>` property (which by the way needs to start with lower case).

Comment: Thanks for the rolename. I am using local document so rolename will be ignored I believe.

Comment: What language are using?  I'll try to code something up and test...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the message "There are no recipients to address" because you have already filled out the recipient information for your two signers so there's no info for the Agent to enter.  To resolve try removing the name and email for each (or just one of those fields) and the agent will then be able to set their info.  I just test this and it worked once I removed those fields for the signers.

So, your recipients section of your xml should looks something like this:

```
<recipients>
  <agents>
     <agent>
        <email>custEmail</email>
        <name>recipientNameCust</name>
        <recipientId>1</recipientId>
        <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
        <canEditRecipientEmails>true</canEditRecipientEmails>
        <canEditRecipientNames>true</canEditRecipientNames>
     </agent>
  </agents>
  <signers>
     <signer>
        <recipientId>2</recipientId>
        <routingOrder>2</routingOrder>
        <tabs>
           <signHereTabs>
              <signHere>
                 <anchorString>SIGNED on behalf of the Customer</anchorString>
                 <anchorXOffset>10</anchorXOffset>
                 <anchorYOffset>50</anchorYOffset>
                 <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                 <anchorUnits>Pixels</anchorUnits>
                 <documentId>1</documentId>
                 <recipientId>2</recipientId>
                 <tabLabel>Sign Here1</tabLabel>
                 <name>SignHere1</name>
              </signHere>
           </signHereTabs>
        </tabs>
     </signer>
     <signer>
        <recipientId>3</recipientId>
        <routingOrder>3</routingOrder>
        <tabs>
           <signHereTabs>
              <signHere>
                 <anchorString>SIGNED on behalf of Total Gas</anchorString>
                 <anchorXOffset>10</anchorXOffset>
                 <anchorYOffset>50</anchorYOffset>
                 <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                 <anchorUnits>Pixels</anchorUnits>
                 <documentId>1</documentId>
                 <recipientId>3</recipientId>
                 <tabLabel>Sign Here2</tabLabel>
                 <name>SignHere2</name>
              </signHere>
           </signHereTabs>
        </tabs>
     </signer>
  </signers>
</recipients>
```

Comment: Thanks Ergin, that is what I mentioned in my query. If I dont include name and email of singer1 then agent can add but if I include them then agent cant see signer1 name and email and agent cant modify them. If you do the same scenario from the portal, agentcan see the signer1's name and email and also modify.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying now, sorry for missing that bit.  So far I'm getting the same thing as you, no matter what settings I include it seems that if you specify the email and name for a signer that the Agent is not allowed to edit their information.  I will log this as a bug on DocuSign's side and see what the response is.  I'll post updates here when possible...